# Heap allocation behaves weird - Android

Tags: android, eclipse, memory-management, heap-memory

I cannot understand what is happening here - I have been creating a small project just to learn about rotation of an image. But this is not relevant here.

So - I have been doing this before and know how heap works, but right know I cannot get it.

In this small Eclipse project I put an image in the drawable-mdpi folder. The image is

```
1300 * 1950
```

So simply - this image will occupy about the following amount of ram (heap)

```
10 MB (1300 * 1950 * 4)
```

Red, gree, blue and Alpha. Thats it!

But what is happening. Well see the logcat below!!! the heap of 63 MB for my Samsung Galaxy S3 is almost exhausted.

```
 02-17 08:50:05.144: I/dalvikvm-heap(21097): Grow heap (frag case) to   22.494MB for 10140016-byte allocation
 02-17 08:50:05.164: D/dalvikvm(21097): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 5% free 22152K/23175K, paused 12ms+2ms, total 22ms
 02-17 08:50:05.329: D/dalvikvm(21097): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 5% free 22152K/23175K, paused 11ms, total 11ms
 02-17 08:50:05.429: I/dalvikvm-heap(21097): Grow heap (frag case) to 61.174MB for 40560016-byte allocation
 02-17 08:50:05.449: D/dalvikvm(21097): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 2% free 61761K/62791K, paused 11ms+3ms, total 22ms
 02-17 08:50:06.109: D/libEGL(21097): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
 02-17 08:50:06.119: D/libEGL(21097): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
 02-17 08:50:06.124: D/libEGL(21097): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
 02-17 08:50:06.179: D/(21097): Device driver API match
 02-17 08:50:06.179: D/(21097): Device driver API version: 10
 02-17 08:50:06.179: D/(21097): User space API version: 10 
 02-17 08:50:06.179: D/(21097): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Fri Sep 28 10:42:56 KST 2012 
 02-17 08:50:06.254: D/OpenGLRenderer(21097): Enabling debug mode 0
```

First it allocates properly - you can see 10 MB (according to my calculations) and a heap well above that - that is 20 MB. So far so good. BUT THEN IT CONTINUES TO ALLOCATE MEMORY FAR ABOVE THAT LEVEL. Like there was another image of 40 MB (4 times the previous) so the allocated heap ends up in 61 MB, almost tangenting out of memory.

What did I miss here or is it a bug? I have checked all the drawable folders and I know I run this app and not another. I recreated the project to be sure, even changed the image name. restarted the computer AND the device

this is the source code

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageView imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image1);
}
```

the xml-file

```
   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

more info: The device is rooted